# Copy int to Char array

Tags: c, pointers, buffer

I have this buffer which I use for store some different types of data:

```
int d;
char *current_Results;
char Results[1000];
current_Results = Results;
```

Now, I copy to this buffer the next data:

```
d = 50;
memcpy(current_Results, &d, sizeof(d));
printf("Current data is - %d\n", (int)(*current_Results));   // "Current data is - 50" Output OK!.

(current_Results)+= sizeof(d);

d = -20;
memcpy(current_Results, &d, sizeof(d));
printf("Current data is - %d\n", (int)(*current_Results));   // "Current data is - 1" Output WRONG!.
(current_Results)+= sizeof(d);
... and so on - wrong output later on...
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: The code doesn't compile, are you sure you meant current_Results = &Results;?

Comment: It will compile on some system, but will get a warning

Comment: I did a mistake when i copied it to here. just fixed it tough.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`(int)(*current_Results)` is not interpreting the bytes that are found at that location as an integer as you seem to expect. It is taking the one character found there and casts that to an `int`. You probably mean `*(int*)current_Results`.

But all of what you are doing here may not be well defined because your are trying to access `int*` and arbitrary alignments. Don't do that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Dont do that', Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Don't cast arbitrarily aligned `char*` into a pointer to another data type. This calls for trouble. Usually a compiler wouldn't complain since he can't know what the alignement will be during execution. Accessing an object through wrong alignment leads to undefined behavior. In most of the cases it will just send you a SIGBUS in the middle of an execution when you hit a corner case for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

We can point a pointer to array in three ways..

First way is to take the first element from array and give its address to pointer

```
current_Results = &Result[0];
```

Second way is just to use array name..In almost all case **array name itself gives array base address..**

```
current_Results = Result;
```

Third way it what you used now..Use & operator on array base address..I think you got a warning when you compiled, right?

```
current_Results = &Result;
```

In the first two ways, you are actually a creating a normal char pointer, which will increment by size of one char (1 byte on most system) when we increment the pointer. ie If current_Results is pointing to address 1000, current_Results++ will make it point to 1001.

In the third case, what you are actually creating is a character array pointer(each one a size of 1000 bytes). When you increment it it will increment by 1000 (which is your array size here). ie **Pointer increments by data types**.. In first two cases your data type is char *, but in third case via assignment you are making the datatype of current_Results as char[1000]. So it will increment out of the array..Just print the address current_Result carrying,

```
printf("%u\n",current_Results);
```

and see if it is incrementing the way you thought. You will understand then. Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, if you have `current_results = Results;`.